# React Router Won't Work Without Refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, redux

Basically, the Route component will not trigger on the click of a Link that changes the path; but after a refresh, the correct component is shown. What could solve the issue?

App component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
/**
 * Import Router
 */
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
/**
 * Import custom components
 */
import IndexComponent from '../components/index_component';
import LoginComponent from '../components/login_component';
/**
 * Import containers
 */
import Navbar from '../containers/Navbar';
import Footer from '../containers/Footer';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
                    <Route path="/" component={IndexComponent} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Login Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class LoginComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>LOGIN COMP</div>
        );
    }
}

export default LoginComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose all your components inside `<Router>` that will solve your issue.

```
<Router>
    <Navbar />
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
        <Route path="/" component={IndexComponent} />
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
</Router>
```

Comment: The problem persists, even through these changes, I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution:

```
   import React from 'react';
   import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
   import IndexComponent from '../components/index_component';
   import LoginComponent from '../components/login_component';


        <Router>
          <Switch>
             <Route path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
            <Route path="/" component={IndexComponent} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
```